# Get data type from PropertyDeclarationSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

i am working on source generator and i need to read properties data type as string
[image]

Is there any solution to get data type name such as int, string, bool, etc...?

EDIT:
`var typeName = property.Type.ToString();` throws exception
[image]

EDIT 2:

```
public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        var model = new TemplateModel();


        var syntaxReceiver = (SolnetParsableClassExplorer)context.SyntaxReceiver;

        syntaxReceiver?.SolnetDtos.ForEach(dto =>
        {
            var typeNodeSymbol = context.Compilation
                .GetSemanticModel(dto.SyntaxTree)
                .GetDeclaredSymbol(dto);

            var dataClass = new DataClassModel();

            foreach (var member in dto.DescendantNodes())
            {
                if (member is PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
                {
                    dataClass.AddProperty(property);
                }
            }

            dataClass.ClassName = dto.Identifier.ValueText;
            model.DataClassModels.Add(dataClass);
        });

        ...
    }

    internal class SolnetParsableClassExplorer : ISyntaxReceiver
    {
        public List<ClassDeclarationSyntax> SolnetDtos { get; } = new();

        public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
        {
            if (syntaxNode is ClassDeclarationSyntax classSyntax &&
                classSyntax.HaveAttribute("SolnetDto"))
            {
                SolnetDtos.Add(classSyntax);
            }
        }
    }

internal class DataClassModel
{
    public List<DataField> Properties = new List<DataField>();
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public int Size => Properties.Sum(p => p.Size);

    public void AddProperty(PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
    {
        // Here generator throw exception
        var typeName = property.Type.ToString();

        Properties.Add(
        new DataField
        {
            PropertyName = property.Identifier.ValueText,
            DataType = typeName,
            Size = GetPropertySize(compilation, property, typeName),
            WriteMethod = GetWriteMethod(typeName),
            ReadMethod = GetReadMethod(typeName),
            Offset = Size
        });            
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the _syntactic_ element or the _semantic_ element? That is, do you want different outputs for `int Foo { get; }`, `Int32 Foo { get; }` and `global::System.Int32 Foo { get; }`? All three of these properties are of the same type, just written in different ways.

Comment: Please share minimum reproducible code

Comment: I cannot reproduce the `NullReferenceException` with the example code you have posted: `PropertyDeclarationSyntax property` is not null, and `PropertyDeclarationSyntax.Type` cannot be null either. I tested it with _Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 3.8.0_.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly. To retrieve the string representation, you could use the `TypeSyntax.ToString()`

```
var strType = propertyDeclarationSyntax.Type.ToString();
```

For example, for the following

```
public string Bar1 { get; set; }
public int Bar2 { get; set; }
public long Bar3 { get; set; }
```

Result

```
Property Bar1 : string
Property Bar2 : int
Property Bar3 : long
```

Comment: `var typeName = property.Type.ToString();`
` throw System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` even if type is not null

Comment: @Daniel I wasn't successfully reproduce a scenario there property/Type is null as the per the code you given in OP. Are we missing something in OP ?